# Difference Between Have been and Have Had

Tags: present-perfect

We often use sentence Like this

1. It has been a mistake.
2. It has been enthralling.
3. He has been rewarded.

That means, we can use noun,adjective and verb past perticiple just after has been. So my question is if I write a sentence like this

**Facebook has been many pernicious effects .** Will it be wrong?

Though some of my friends said to me It will be

**Facebook has had many pernicious effects.**

But I dont understand why my sentence has not been correct.

Answer (score 1):

> Social networking sites such as facebook have been many pernicious
>   effects on society.

Isn't right.

The present perfect is composed of two forms: present perfect and present perfect continuous, both are written in the continuous form, however: **Social networking sites such as facebook have been many pernicious effects on society** isn't right because when you use **been**, you imply one continuous action, something that is ongoing, consequently, it would need a verb in the continuous form to perform that function: **Social networking sites such as facebook have been causing many effects to the society**.

Oh, if you intended to use it in the passive voice:

> Social networking sites such as facebook have been deleted due to the damages they have caused to the society

As you can see, if you don't use the present perfect continuous proceded by a verb *-ING*, it's probably in the passive voice and it means the next word will probably be a verb in the *past participle* or an *adjective*.

And your sentence: **Social networking sites such as facebook have been many pernicious effects on society** isn't right because *pernicious* is being used as an adjective, therefore *facebook can't have been many pernicious effects on society*, it doesn't make sense, but **facebook can for sure have had many pernicious effects on society**.

So, the only way to fit your statement into the present perfect continuous would be:

> Social networking sites such as facebook have been having many
>   pernicious effects on society

[Present perfect x continuous](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/present-perfect-simple-and-present-perfect-continuous)

Answer (score 0):

They are both of **present perfect tense**: "have been" is of the verb **to be**; "have had" is of the verb **to have**.